# Search for a specific word in each line and print rest of the line

Tags: sed, awk, grep, search

I have text file with server URL lines like:

```
request get https://abc.net/search?q=hello/world/hello/word/search=5&size=10
request get https://abc.net/search?q=hello/world/hello/world/hello/word=5
```

In this text file, I want the text after the word "search?q=" string and store in another file
output file:

```
hello/world/hello/word/search=5&size=10
hello/world/hello/word/hello/world=5
hello1world1/hello/world/hello/word
```

Comment: `cut -d= -f2- <in >out`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/search?q=/{s/.*search?q=//;p;}' infile > outfile
```

Explanation:

`/search?q=/` makes the following command set (in curly braces) apply only to lines containing this regex.

`s/.*search?q=//` substitutes the second part (empty) for the first part.

Then `p` prints the line.

The `-n` flag suppresses the default printing of the line.

Actually, you can simplify this like so:

```
sed -n '/.*search?q=/{s///;p;}' infile > outfile
```

Because when the pattern fed to the `s/` command is left blank, the last used pattern is used again.

---

EDIT:  Thanks to RobertL for pointing out a simplification in the comments:

```
sed -n 's/.*search?q=//p' infile > outfile
```

This uses the `p` flag to the `s` command, which only prints out the line if a substitution was made.

Comment: How about `sed -n 's/.*search?q=//p'` ?

Comment: Yes, that works too.  I usually forget about the flags for the `s` command.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of grep supports PCRE, you could use something like

```
grep -oP 'search\?q=\K.*' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

with perl based regex search using lookbehind we can get your required result.

```
grep -oP '(?<=search\?q\=)[^ ]*' *filename*
```

remember to add `\` before `?` and `=` as those are part  of lookbehind regex.